# Play Store doesn't update apps

Tags: applications, google-play-store, updates

I have a Xiaomi Pocophone F1. Today, I noticed that regardless I have a very good internet connection (Wi-Fi), the apps don't update. I didn't face the problem previously, when I clicked "Update all", it updated all apps. I cannot even install new programs.

When I click "Update", it waits for a long time. After that, it shows me an error that the app cannot be installed or updated. I say that the problem is not due to an internet connection because each time I check the connection speed, it is over 100Mbps.

I tried these methods, but none of them worked:

1. I cleared the cache on the Play Store
2. I cleared all data on the Play Store
3. I rebooted the phone many times
4. I check internet speed using a speed test program (the speed of connection is over 100 Mbps)

Please suggest to me the ways to fix it.

Comment: How much flash memory is free on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

You have tried the right options. Next you have these.

5. Revert to factory versions both Play Store and Play Services. Restart and wait around 10 minutes for them to auto-update.
6. Remove your Google account and clear data from the previous apps. Restart phone, re-add your Google account, and retry.
7. Permanently disable the Play Store auto-update feature and manually update apps.